# angular material sidebar displaying horizontal

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material  "MatSidenavModule" to display side navigation bar i'm displaying this based on condition show and hide .while clicking show i'm getting sidebar in horizontal format instead of vertical .

```
<mat-sidenav-container *ngIf="showSideBar">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>

      <a mat-list-item > Accounts </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Create Account </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Contacts </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Create Contact </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Activities </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Create Activity </a>
      <a mat-list-item (click)="sidenav.toggle()" href="" mat-list-item>Close</a>

    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div style="height: 88vh;">

    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do some changes.
I showing you the example of the html that you need to replace yours:

```
<mat-sidenav-container >
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav opened mode=side> 
    <mat-nav-list>

      <a mat-list-item > Accounts </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Create Account </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Contacts </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Create Contact </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Activities </a>
      <a mat-list-item > Create Activity </a>
      <a mat-list-item (click)="sidenav.toggle()" href="" mat-list-item>Close</a>

    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div style="height: 88vh;">
   temp
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Here you have to set the property **mode** to specify the behavior of the sidenav.

I have tried this and its working. Please remove all additional elements from page once and see whether its working or not. And also remove all the css applied to this page.

Comment: Have you applied any custom css in this?

Comment: Hey, I have edited the answer. please go  and try this once. Remove all the other elements for once.